# bash + Linux + how to ignore the character "!"

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I want to send little script to remote machine by ssh

the script is

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep 1
reboot
```

but I get event not found - because the "!"

```
 ssh 183.34.4.9 "echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\reboot>'/tmp/file"
 -bash: !/bin/bash\nsleep: event not found
```

how to ignore the "!" char so script will so send successfully by ssh?

remark I cant use "\" before the "!" because I get

```
more /tmp/file
#\!/bin/bash
sleep 1
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `set +H` before your command to disable `! style history substitution`:

```
set +H
ssh 183.34.4.9 "echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\reboot>'/tmp/file"

# enable hostory expnsion again
set -H
```

Comment: is it possible to do chmod +x on the same line ?

Comment: yes ( I not want to run ssh twice because the chmod +x )

Comment: what I mean is if I can add the chmod +x /tmp/file after "#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\reboot>'/tmp/file"    as #!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\reboot>'/tmp/file ; chmod +x /tmp/file

Comment: You can use: `ssh 183.34.4.9 "echo -e '#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\nreboot' > /tmp/file; chmod +x /tmp/file"`

Answer (score 0):

I think your command line is not well formated. You can send this:

```
ssh 183.34.4.9 'echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\nreboot">/tmp/file'
```

When I say "not well formated" I mean you put ">" inside the "echo" and you forgot to add "n" before "reboot", and you put "\reboot", wich will be interpreted as "CR" (carriage return) followed by "eboot" command (which I don't think that exists).

But what did the trick here is to invert the comas changing (') with (") and viceversa.

Comment: About your question "chmod +x on the same line"... What about googleing "bash more than one command in one line"?... Anyway, you can add "; chmod +x /tmp/file" at the end of your commandline like this: `ssh 183.34.4.9 'echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\nreboot">/tmp/file; chmod +x /tmp/file'`

Answer (score 0):

Bash is running interactively (which means that you are feeding commands to it from the standard input and not `exec(2)`ing a command from a shell script) so you **don't need to include the line `#!/bin/bash`** in that case (even more, bash should just ignore it, but not the included bang, as it is part of the active history mechanism)

But why? the first two characters in an executable file (any file capable of being `exec(2)`ed from secondary storage, not your case) have a special meaning (for the kernel and for the shell): they are the **magic number** that *identifies the kind of executable file the kernel is loading*.  This allows the kernel to select the proper executable loading routines depending on the binary executable format (and what allows you for example to execute BSD programs in linux kernels, and viceversa)

A special value for this magic numbers is composed **by the two characters `#` and `!`** (in that order) that forces the kernel to read the complete first line of that file and load the executable file specified in that line instead, allowing you to execute shell scripts for different interpreters directly from the command line.  And it is done on purpose, as the `#` character is commonly in shell script parlance a comment character. This only happens when the shell that is interpreting the commands *is not an interactive shell*.  When the shell loads a script with those characters, it normally reads the first line also to check if it has the `#!` mark and load the proper interpreter, by replicating the kernel function that does this.  Despite of being a comment for the shell, it does this to allow to treat as executables files that are not stored on secondary storage (the only ones the `exec(2)` system call can deal with), but coming from `stdin` (as happens to yours).

As your shell is running interactively and you do want to execute its commands without a shell change, you don't need that line and can completely eliminate it without having to disable the bang character.

Sorry, but the solution given about executing the shell with `-H` option will probably not be viable, as the shell executing the commands **is the login shell** in the target machine, so you cannot provide specific parameters to it (parameters are selected by the login(8) program and normally don't include arbitrary parameters like `-H`).

The best solution is to fully eliminate the `#!/bin/bash` line, as you are not going to `exec(2)` that program in the target.  In case you want to select the shell from the input line (case the user has a different shell installed as login shell), it is better to invoke the wanted shell in the command line and pass it (through stdin, or making it read the shell script as a file) the shell commands you wan to execute (but again, without the `#!` line).

## NOTE

Its important to ensure you'll execute the whole thing, so it's best to pass all the script contents in the destination target, and once assured you have passed the whole thing to execute it as a whole.  Then your `#!` first line will be properly processed, as the executable will be run by means of an `exec(2)` made from the kernel.

Example:

```
DIRECTORY=/bla/bla
FILE=/path/to/file
OUTPUT=/path/to/output

# this is the command we want to pass through the line
cat <<EOF | ssh user@target "cat >>/tmp/shell.sh"
cd $DIRECTORY
foo $FILE >$OUTPUT
exit 0
EOF 
# we have copied the script file in a remote /tmp/shell.sh
# and we are sure it has passed correctly, so it's ready 
# for local execution there.
# now, execute it.
# the remote shell won't be interactive, and you'll ensure that it is /bin/bash
ssh user@target "/bin/bash /tmp/shell.sh" >remote_shell.out
```

A more sophisticate system is one that allows to to sign the shell script before sending, and verify the script signature before executing it, so you are protected against possible trojan horse attacks.  But this is out of scope on this explanation.

Another alternative is to use the `batch(2)` command remotely and pass it all the commands you want executed.  you'll get a sessionless executing environment, more suitable to the task you are demanding (despite the fact that you'll get the script output by email to the target user running the script)

Answer (score 0):

> Interactively, beware that ! triggers history expansion inside double quotes

from here: https://riptutorial.com/bash/example/2465/quoting-literal-text

my recommended solution is to use single quotes to define the string (and either escape single quotes `\'` or use double quotes `"` within the string):

```bash
 ssh 183.34.4.9 'echo -e "#!/bin/bash\nsleep 1\reboot>"/tmp/file'
```